# trying to set a different language for date times with Flask-Moment

Tags: python, flask, momentjs

I have started doing some simple web development with Flask.  I am going through this book about it and I have this code in the template for the page I'm using with Flask-Moment

```
<p>The local date and time is {{ moment(current_time).format('LLL') }}.</p>
<p>That was {{ moment(current_time).fromNow(refresh=True) }}</p>
```

then it says I can change it with

```
{{ moment.lang('es') }}
```

I've tried changing it to double quotes and searched for hours to get this to display the answer in Spanish and it won't change.  I realize the local date and time up above is in english but the time formatted should be in Spanish. Right now it's giving me

```
The local date and time is Thursday, December 4 2014 12:40 PM.
```

`Thursday` and `December` should be changing into Spanish or at least I would assume.

I've searched a ton to why this won't work or what is wrong and I can't find or get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include more of the template to show where all the Moment-related statements are placed?

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this and it works just fine for me. I also happen to be the author of Flask-Moment, and also the author of the book you are reading. :)

I went to file `templates/base.html` and made the following change near the bottom of the file:

```
{% block scripts %}
{{ super() }}
{{ moment.include_moment() }}
{{ moment.lang('es') }}        <--- I added this line
{% endblock %}
```

Then the application shows me a very funny output half in English and half in Spanish:

```
The local date and time is 4 de diciembre de 2014 22:02.
That was hace unos segundos.
```

Note how the month, the relative timing and even the 24-hour clock were changed to a Spanish style.

Comment: May I ask how come if I use 'zh' as lang, it won't work. It only works if I input "zh_CN"

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to have a more dynamic behavior and after looking into the Flask-Moment source code I came up with the following solution to autodetect the browser language (which works nicely for me):

```
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
    {{ moment.locale(auto_detect=True) }}
{% endblock %}
```